Using WebAuthenticator successfully returns a Google access_token, but how do I use that to access my API's endpoints?
I am using the following to get an access_token from Google.
            var authUrl = new Uri(authenticationUrl + scheme);
            var callbackUrl = new Uri("xamarinessentials://");
            
            r = await WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(authUrl, callbackUrl);

Now that I have the access token, what do I have to do on my API to access my protected endpoints?
The WebAuthenticator hits an endpoint on my API to authenticate
        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity("Application");
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync("Application", new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity));

        var googleToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("Google");
        var appToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("Application");
        var extToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("External");

        var claims = authenticateResult.Principal?.Identities.FirstOrDefault()?.Claims;
        var email = claims?.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;
        
        // Get parameters to send back to the callback
        var qs = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "access_token", authenticateResult.Properties?.GetTokenValue("access_token")! },
            { "refresh_token", authenticateResult.Properties?.GetTokenValue("refresh_token") ?? string.Empty },
            { "expires", (authenticateResult.Properties?.ExpiresUtc?.ToUnixTimeSeconds() ?? -1).ToString() },
            { "email", email! }
        };

        // Build the result url
        var url = callbackScheme + "://#" + string.Join(
            "&",
            qs.Where(kvp => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(kvp.Value) && kvp.Value != "-1")
                .Select(kvp => $"{WebUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Key)}={WebUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value)}"));

        // Redirect to final url
        Request.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(url);

A coookie is written, but my subsequent requests from my app for protected endpoints are not successful, so the cookie is not being used.
Do I need to attach a cookie to the request from my app? How do I do that?
As a test I was able to get the token info on my api with the following
var url = $"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token={accessToken}";

I'm really lost. How can I use my google account to access protected resources on my API?
